# In eclipse AVD, I got 'Unfortunately ~ has stopped working'

Tags: java, android, eclipse, package

I was making ImageView activity and when I try to run it through AVD, it stopped.

There are no typing errors.

How can I fix it? I need your help.

Below is my code

```
package com.android.imgview;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}
}
```

Comment: Clean project, restart emulator, try it on a real device, and if all else fails, post the actual error logs. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Restart the emulator.I am also facing such problem sometime but restarting the emulator fixes this.